# How would I implement a rfind in Lua with the arguments?

Tags: python, string, lua

For example, I would like to do something like this in lua:

```py
s = "Hey\n There And Yea\n"

print(s.rfind("\n", 0, 5))
```

I've tried making this in lua with the string.find function:

```lua
local s = "Hey\n There And Yea\n"

local _, p = s:find(".*\n", -5)

print(p)
```

But these aren't producing the same results. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this to making it the same as rfind?

Comment: For clarification for future readers: The output of the Python code is "3" (4th letter from the left). rfind finds the HIGHEST, or RIGHTMOST, index, but the OP provided a 0-5 range, so it returns the rightmost within that range. The output of the Lua code is p = 19, p being the end index of the substring (_ would be the start). I do not yet know the answer to this problem. I will try to come up with something or at least point out the errors in the invocation of the find method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The pattern I have written will only work for single-char substrings like the one the asker used as a test case. Skip ahead to the next bold header to see that answer, or read on for an explanation of some of the things they did wrong with their attempt. Skip to the very final bold header for a general, inefficient solution for multi-char substrings**

I have tried to recreate the output of python `mystring.rfind` with lua `mystring:find`, it only works for single-character substrings. Later I will show you a function that does it for all cases but is a pretty bad loop.

As a recap (to address what you're doing wrong), let's talk about `mystringvar:find("pattern", index)`, sugar for `string.find(mystringvar, "pattern", index)`. This will return `start, stop` indexes.

The optional Index sets the start, not the end, but a negative index will count backwards from the 'right minus index' to end of string (an index of -1 will only evaluate the last character, -2 the last 2). This is not the desired behavior.

Instead of trying to use the index to create a substring, you should create a substring like this:
`mystringvar:sub(start, end)` will extract and return the substring from start to end (1 indexed, inclusive end). So to recreate Python's 0-5 (0 indexed, exclusive end), use 1-5.

Now note that these methods can be chained into `string:sub(x, y):find("")` but I will break it up for ease of reading. Without further ado, I present you:
**The answer**

```lua
local s = "Hey\n There And Yea\n"
local substr = s:sub(1,5)
local start, fin = substr:find("\n[^\n]-$")
print(start, ",", fin)
```

I had a few half measure solutions, but to make sure what I was writing would work for multiple substring instances (the 1-5 substring only contains 1), I tested with the substring and the whole string. Observe:
output with sub(1, 5):  `4   ,  5`
output with sub(1, 19) (the whole length): `19   ,  19`

These both correctly report the beginning of the rightmost substring, but note that the "fin" index goes to the end of the sentence, I will explain in a second. I hope this is fine because rfind only returns the starting index anyway, so this should be an appropriate replacement.

Let's reread the code to see how it works:
sub I've already explained
There is no longer a need for index in string.find
Alright, what's this pattern `"\n[^\n]-$"`?
`$` - anchor to end of sentence
`[^x]` - match "not x"
`-` - as few matches as possible (even 0) of the previous character or set (in this case, `[^\n]`). This means that if a string ends with your substring, it will still work)
It begins with \n, so all together it means: "Find me a line break, but followed by no other line breaks, up to the end of the sentence." This means that even though your substring only contains 1 instance of \n, if you were to use this function on a string with multiple substrings, you would still get the highest index, as rfind does.

Note that string.find does not conform to pattern groups (`()`), so it would be vain to wrap the `\n` in a group. As a consequence, I cannot stop end-anchoring `$` from extending the `fin` variable to the end of the sentence.

I hope this works well for you.

**Function to do this for substrings of any length**
I will not be explaining this one.

```lua
function string.rfind(str, substr, plain) --plain is included for you to pass to find if you wish to ignore patterns
  assert(substr ~= "") --An empty substring would cause an endless loop. Bad!
  local plain = plain or false --default plain to false if not included
  local index = 0
  --[[
    Watch closely... we continually shift the starting point after each found index until nothing is left. 
        At that point, we find the difference between the original string's length and the new string's length, to see how many characters we cut out. 
  ]]--
  while true do
    local new_start, _ = string.find(str, substr, index, plain) --index will continually push up the string to after whenever the last index was.
    if new_start == nil then --no match is found
            if index == 0 then return nil end   --if no match is found and the index was never changed, return nil (there was no match)
      return #str - #str:sub(index)  --if no match is found and we have some index, do math.
    end
    --print("new start", new_start)
    index = new_start + 1 --ok, there was some kind of match. set our index to whatever that was, and add 1 so that we don't get stuck in a loop of rematching the start of our substring.
  end
end
```

If you'd like to see my entire "test suite" for [this](https://pastebin.com/8Q6FiXaf)...

Answer (score 2):

Lua has a little known function `string.reverse` that reverses all characters of a string. While this is rarely needed, the function can typically be used to make a reverse search inside a string.
So to implement `rfind`, you want to search the *reverse* pattern inside the *reverse* original string, and finally make some arithmetics to obtain the offset from the original string.
Here is the code that mimics Python `rfind`:

```
function rfind(subject, tofind, startIdx, endIdx)
    startIdx = startIdx or 0
    endIdx = endIdx or #subject
    subject = subject:sub(startIdx+1, endIdx):reverse()
    tofind = tofind:reverse()
    local idx = subject:find(tofind)
    return idx and #subject - #tofind - idx + startIdx + 1 or -1
end

print(rfind("Hello World", "H")) --> 0
print(rfind("Hello World", "l")) --> 9
print(rfind("foo foo foo", "foo")) --> 8
print(rfind("Hello World", "Toto")) --> -1
print(rfind("Hello World", "l", 1, 4)) --> 3
```

Note that this version of `rfind` uses Python index convention, starting at `0` and returning `-1` if string is not found. It would be more coherent in Lua to have 1-based index and to return `nil` when there are no match. The modification would be trivial.

Comment: I was wondering more about how I could implement it with the other arguments, not just asking for the string.

Comment: @JackMurrow No problem, just use `string.sub` to select the substring of interest before reversing it. And account for the start position in the final index computation. See my updated answer.